# Why does this code gives me wrong values?

Tags: c

Why does this function sometimes return an invalid microsecond timestamp:

```
uint64_t get_time_us(){
  struct timespec tp;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp);
  return tp.tv_sec * 1000000 + tp.tv_nsec / 1000;
}
```

if I change the return line to:

```
return ((uint64_t)tp.tv_sec)*1000000 + ((uint64_t) tp.tv_nsec) / 1000;
```

it will no longer fail, and I can't understand why.

Comment: What type is `tp.tv_sec`? What do you expect to happen when `tp.tv_sec * 1000000` is too big to fit in that type?

Comment: What you have here is basically the same problem as `float f = 1 / 2`, and `long long x = 1000000 * 1000000`.  C doesn't "look ahead" to see what the final type will be — that is, in your case it doesn't matter that `get_time_us` is declared as returning `uint64_t`.  Each internal part of an expression is evaluated based on the types of its operands — and an internal part of an expression can therefore overflow before you expected it to.

Comment: `tp.tv_sec * 1000000` is calculated using the type of `tp.tv_sec`. If this overflows, you get an incorrect result.

Comment: Specifically, signed integer overflow, which is UB. Since you already know how to fix this (promote your integer before multiplication), the question is just "what is integer overflow", right?

Comment: Try `return tp.tv_sec * 1000000ULL + tp.tv_nsec / 1000;` and see where that gets you. Since `unsigned long long` is at least 64 bit, it should have plenty of room for `tv_sec * 1000000`.

Comment: Providing an example of an input, expected output and the output you're getting would be helpful.